# Search PHP array for value and get parent key

Tags: php, recursion

I'm not sure why but I'm having trouble working out recursion for this issue. Here is a sample data structure:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [powers] => Array (
                [0] => Array (
                        [power] => Super Strength
                        [scale] => 8
                    )
                [1] => Array (
                        [power] => Invisibility
                        [scale] => 4
                    )
          )
     )
)
```

What I need to do, is pass an array to a recursive function, so like this:

```
get_parent_key($our_array[0]["powers"], "Super Strength");
```

and have the return value be the parent array index, so in this case, `0`. If I were to search for "Invisibility" with this same function, the return value would be `1`.

I'm just brain farting and can't seem to form the correct recursive function. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) for this:

```
$power = 'SuperStrength';
$key = array_search($power, array_column($our_array[0]["powers"], 'power'));
echo "$key\n";
$power = 'Invisibility';
$key = array_search($power, array_column($our_array[0]["powers"], 'power'));
echo "$key\n";
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

Note that `array_search` returns `false` (which can be equivalent to 0) if it doesn't find a value, so when checking the result you should use `!== false` to test for success. For example:

```
$power = 'Flying';
$key = array_search($power, array_column($our_array[0]["powers"], 'power'));
if ($key !== false) echo "$key\n";
else echo "power $power not found!\n";
```

Output:

```
power Flying not found!
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/bQ9Be)

Comment: Yup, that did it. I was overthinking it and forget about `array_column()`. Thank you!

Comment: But what if powers is an associative array ?

Comment: @VenkataKrishna the code would need changing to take account of that. If it's an issue for you, ask a question.